# How to make AJAX call to myself from Joomla! module?

Tags: ajax, url, module, joomla

I wrote a module that is dependent on some third party device (load, parse & display). Sometimes it takes 5 seconds for it to respond so I tried to ajaxify this part.

My Joomla! module is ready as well as code with AJAX (mootools) but I can't figure out the URL to access my module php file "infused" by Joomla! (something like /index.php?option=com_content). I can hardcode and access it (/modules/mod_a/xyz.php) but I will run into "direct access not allowed" which is no trouble, but I don't have the Joomla! context which I pretty much miss.

All I found utilizes components which I would very much like to avoid.

Thanks for suggestions,

Regards,

Marek

Comment: The only way is to create a component. This will allow you to call a url.

Comment: :sigh: That's what I was afraid of. I could do XSS/CORS and parse data in JS but component seems more viable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did write the simplest component I could (no MVC):

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$task = JRequest::getWord('task');
if ($task == "getCurrentTemp") {
 // return temperature
}
```

This can be printed (heredoc) to JS by **JURI::current()."index.php?option=com_xzy&task=getCurrentTemp"**.
Not being able to access module sucks a little bit but I understand that from architectural point of view.

Comment: After done creating the simple component, how I get the return value from the default.php of my module?  Do I have to include files of the component to get their classes so I can access the method-function-task?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to your module by url. The only way to create very simple component with one model and one view for this purpose. Or you could add one `task` to one the components installed in your site.