# Cannot access my custom Joomla module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and I created a custom module from scratch.

Basically, the purpose of this module is to be embedded in an article and to perform ajax request and display some updated data.

I do not manage to have Ajax working (but this is another topic).

The thing is, when I call the url: `index.php?option=com_mymodule` I have a 404 error. The module is public and is embedded in a public article.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php?option=com_mymodule

Did you make a component or a module? This is a bit confusing.

You say you want the module embedded in an article. I that case you would normally use something like {loadposition positionname} where positionname is the name of the position the module is assigned to.

Comment: I made a module. Ok I though that could be accessed via the URL for test purposes. The idea behind that is to test the Ajax request that this module should perform. What I understood is that there is a way to call a particular task within a module's controller.

Comment: Test as in an automated test or test where you just want to  try it manually?

Comment: I though I could test the module's controller's method via an URL, but it seems I was wrong then :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a module by an url, however you can access a component by url. More information is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6755134/1271566).

Comment: Thanks, this link is interesting. What I have done so far is created the module and embedded it in an article with loadposition. This is working fine. But when it comes to test the AJAX query (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398122/cannot-have-ajax-working-in-my-joomla-module), it failed. I just though I could add a method in the module's controller. What you are saying it to use a component and not a module, right ?